# Rigid body simulation inconsitencies

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have an array modifier set up on a curve and I'm trying to make a domino effect. Half of the simulation is normal but the other half is flying about randomly even though they all have same properties and everything is the same. I can't figure out what the problem is.

Leaving the `.blend` so you can run the simulation and mess about with it.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/gu171w0r4e8acr0/GLICHY.blend

Comment: Please add more information - preferably some images, animated if possible - to show what is happening, rather than rely on someone downloading your .blend file. My first thought (just a guess) is that if you’ve created multiple objects from an Array modifier that the resultant objects might not have their origin/centre of mass set correctly and this can cause the simulation to produce unexpected results. Select all objects and use the Origin toolbox option to set the origin to the centre of mass.